# link didn't work outside of div in notification dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating Notification section, where the link is provided on Notification in dropdown menu, but the link on Notification is not working, it is showing the link which i provided in left bottom of the browser but it can't clickable?

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="notificationLink" title="Notifications"><i class="fa fa-globe"><span class="badge badge-notify">.</span></i></a>

  <div id="notificationContainer">
<div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
<div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<a href="notifications.php#1" id="details-container-notification">
<ul class="area-notification">
<li>
<div class="profile-image-notification">
<div id="profile-container-notification">
<image id="profileImageNotification" src="../images/img_avatar.png" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="description-notification"><p>KEntury Fried Chicken, KFC is now following you is now following you, can you want to follow back him , Thanks.</p></li>
 </ul>
</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#notificationContainer {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
margin-left: -250px;
width: 400px;
display: none;
z-index: 1;
}

#notificationTitle {
z-index: 1000;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 18px;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 384px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
font-family:Bookman Old Style ;
}

#notificationsBody {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
min-height:100px;
font-family:Bookman Old Style ;
margin-bottom:0px;
}

#details-container-notification{
    margin-top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0%;
    font-size: 14px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: darkblack;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Bookman Old Style ;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f5f8fa;
    padding:10px;
}

#details-container-notification:hover{
    background-color:#fafafa;
}


.area-notification{
    width:100%;
}

#profile-container-notification {
    float:left;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-right:2%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#profile-container-notification img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

#notificationFooter{
background-color: #e9eaed;
text-align: center;
padding: 8px;
width:100%;
font-size: 18px;
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Bookman Old Style ;
}

.badge-notify{
   background:#3897f0;
   position:relative;
   top: -10px;
   left: -35px;
  }
```

**JSFIDDLE:- https://jsfiddle.net/r33osLt9/1/**

Comment: can you please add a working fiddle

Comment: yes, wait a moment

Comment: can i add the whole page, the it will be eassy??

Comment: post your url, thats use full

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r33osLt9/

Comment: your fiddle working good

Comment: Full Fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/r33osLt9/1/

Comment: this also working good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133795/discussion-between-naila-and-nakhhhh).

Comment: and what is solution for link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know exactly what your issue , if my thought is right remove 
`return false` from you js , check with working fiddle

```
$("#notificationContainer").click(function() {
  //return false
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r33osLt9/2/

just try with this also

```js
$(function(){
 
 $("#notificationLink").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); /* this will block the link */
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#notificationContainer").slideToggle(300);
 });
 
 $("#settingLink").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); /* this will block the link */
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#settingContainer").fadeToggle(300);
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', function(){
  $("#notificationContainer").hide();
  $("#settingContainer").hide();
 });
 
});
```

```css
.navigation {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#notificationContainer {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 width: 400px;
 display: none;
 z-index: 1;
}
#notificationTitle {
 z-index: 1000;
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 384px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
 font-family: Bookman Old Style;
}
#notificationsBody {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
 min-height: 100px;
 font-family: Bookman Old Style;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#details-container-notification {
 margin-top: 0%;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 0%;
 font-size: 14px;
 word-spacing: 1px;
 line-height: 150%;
 color: darkblack;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Bookman Old Style;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f8fa;
 padding: 10px;
}
#details-container-notification:hover {
 background-color: #fafafa;
}
.area-notification {
 width: 100%;
}
#profile-container-notification {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -ms-border-radius: 50%;
 -o-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#profile-container-notification img {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}
#notificationFooter {
 background-color: #e9eaed;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Bookman Old Style;
}
.badge-notify {
 background: #3897f0;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 left: -35px;
}
#settingContainer {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 width: 180px;
 display: none;
 z-index: 1;
}
#settingsBody {
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
 height: 50px;
 font-family: Bookman Old Style;
}
.area-setting {
 width: 100%;
}
#details-container-setting {
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 1%;
 font-size: 18px;
 word-spacing: 1px;
 color: darkblack;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Bookman Old Style;
 line-height: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 0%;
 padding: 10px;
}
#details-container-setting:hover {
 background-color: #fafafa;
}
.icon-bar a {
 width: 50px;
 float: left;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: black;
}
.icon1 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="icon-bar"> <a href="../search/search.php" class="icon1" title="Search"><i class="fa fa-search"><span></span></i></a> <a href="../messages/messages.php" title="Messages"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><span class="badge badge-notify">.</span></i></a> <a href="" id="notificationLink" title="Notifications"><i class="fa fa-globe"><span class="badge badge-notify">.</span></i></a>
    <div id="notificationContainer">
      <div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
      <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <a href="notifications.php#1" id="details-container-notification">
          <ul class="area-notification">
            <li>
              <div class="profile-image-notification">
                <div id="profile-container-notification">
                  <image id="profileImageNotification" src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="description-notification">
              <p>KEntury Fried Chicken, KFC is now following you is now following you, can you want to follow back him , Thanks.</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </a> </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <a href="notifications.php#2" id="details-container-notification">
          <ul class="area-notification">
            <li>
              <div class="profile-image-notification">
                <div id="profile-container-notification">
                  <image id="profileImageNotification" src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p class="description-notification">KEntury Fried Chicken</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </a> </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <a href="notifications.php#3" id="details-container-notification">
          <ul class="area-notification">
            <li>
              <div class="profile-image-notification">
                <div id="profile-container-notification">
                  <image id="profileImageNotification" src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p class="description-notification">KFC</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </a> </div>
      </div>
      <a href="notifications.php" id="notificationFooter">
      <p>See All</p>
      </a> </div>
    <a href="../settings/settings.php" id="settingLink" title="Settings"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
    <div id="settingContainer">
      <div id="settingsBody" class="setting">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <a href="../edit-profile/edit-profile.php" id="details-container-setting">
          <ul class="area-setting">
            <li>
              <p class="description-setting">Setting</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </a> </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <a href="../logout/logout.php" id="details-container-setting">
          <ul class="area-setting">
            <li>
              <p class="description-setting">Logout</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: issue is, hen you click on notification or setting e.g logout, the link didn't goes to that page, why??

Comment: can i ask another question??

Comment: if you see the notification and setting overflow on each other, like when i click open notification container and then click on setting container, the last one didn't close? can you resolve it, for me, Thanks

Comment: i am on big project, so there is lot of problems, and if i need help, so can you please help me, how??

Comment: @Nakhhhh if you want to close any container then u can easily set its css `$(id).css("display", "hide")` or `$(id).hide()`

Comment: @Nakhhhh try with the snippet newly added , i have optimized the code

Answer (score -1):

Your tag a needs to have `display:block`.

If not, the tag a cannot contain a block element. Because of a rule of html the unblock-level element cannot have the block-level element inside. If you do, the unblock-level one will not work well.